# Expand search functionality

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building a website which has multiple tables which detail features of the site such as car pooling, matches, opponents and registered users. I have added a search function which searches for matches on the website but I do not know how to expand upon this so a user can search for car pooling details, opponents and registered users. I could probably just repeat what I have done for matches over again but this seems inefficient and I am sure there must be a way to capture all matching information to the search term entered.

There is a fair bit of code so bear with me please -

**This is in the matches_contoller.rb file:**

```
 def search
 @search_term = params[:q]
 st = "%#{params[:q]}%"
 @matches = Match.where("Opponent like ?", st)


respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @matches }
end  
end
```

**I have added a _search.html.erb to the matches folder with this code:**

```
  <%= form_tag("/search", :method => "post") do %>
  <%= label_tag(:q, "Search for:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:q) %>
  <%= submit_tag("Search") %>
  <% end %>
```

**I have added a search.html.erb to the matches folder with this code:**

```
 <h1>Search Matches Catalog</h1>
 <br />
 <h3>Searching For: <%= @search_term %></h3>
 <table class="catalog">

 <% if @matches.length == 0  %>
 <br />
 <h2>No matches found for this search term!!</h2>
 <% end %>

 <% @matches.each do |match| %>
 <tr>
    <td><%= match.opponent %></td>
    <td><%= match.game %></td>
    <td><%= match.home_away %></td>
    <td><%= match.kick_off.strftime("%d/%m/%Y at %I:%M") %></td>
    <td><%= match.score %></td>
    <td><%= match.result %></td>

</tr>

<% end %>
</table>

<% if session[:login] == 1 %>
<p><%= link_to 'New match', new_match_path %></p>
<% end %>
```

**This has been added to the routes.rb file:**

```
 post '/search' => 'matches#search'
```

**And finally this has been added to the application.html.erb file:**

```
        <div class="searchbox">
        <%= render :partial => 'matches/search' %>
        </div>
```

I realise this is a bit long winded and any advice is greatly appreciated.

If anyone is so enclined I am happy to share my cloud9 development environment for someone to take a look if they feel it would be easier.

Thanks in advance and I hope the question is clear.

Answer (score 0):

I would advice you with [`elasticsearch`](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch), it has flexible and advanced search indices in which you can add the columns you want to search by which satisfies your requirements.

An awesome `elasticsearch` client is [`searckick`](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick). It abstracts all difficulties in `elasticsearch DSL` and simplifies your mission.

First you will need to install `elasticsearch` then add `gem 'searchkick'` to your `Gemfile`.

If you use a Mac
brew install elasticsearch

the same for Linux distributions just replace `brew` by `apt-get` in `ubuntu`, `yum` or `dnf` in Fedora.

Add `searchkick` to your model

```
class Match < ActiveRecord::Base
  searchkick
end
```

To control indexed data use the method `search_data`

```
class Match < ActiveRecord::Base
  searchkick
  def search_data
    {
      opponents: opponents_data,
      details: details
    }
  end

  def opponents_data
    self.opponents.pluck(:name).join(',')
  end
end
```

After that run `Match.reindex` and you can use `Match.search("query")`

Read more about `elasticsearch` and `searchkick` in their respective documentations. (Links attached above)

Comment: Thank you for your response Mohamed. I haven't had a chance to test this but will get back to you in a day or so.